# How to change autocommit in SQLAlchemy in the middle of the application

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a webapp that communicates with a postgres database via SQLAlchemy.
The default value of autocommit=False is good for the most part of the application.
With `autocommit=False`, the following code runs ok.

```
db = sqlalchemy(session_options={'autocommit': False})
...
def func1():
    db.session.add(image1)
    db.session.commit()

def func2():
    db.session.add(image2)
    db.session.commit()

def func3():
    db.session.add(image3)
    db.session.commit()

    db.session.add(image4)
    db.session.commit()
```

I now, want to use single commit for multiple inserts/update operations.
I can change my db session to autocommit=True, and call `db.session.begin()` before every operation, e.g.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={'autocommit': True})
...
def func1():
    db.session.begin()
    db.session.add(image1)
    db.session.commit()

def func2():
    db.session.begin()
    db.session.add(image2)
    db.session.commit()

def func3():
    db.session.begin()
    db.session.add(image3)

    db.session.add(image4)
    db.session.commit()
```

But if I change back to `autocommit = True`, I get an error, that complains about the `db.session.begin()`

```
...
  File "/usr/src/app/web/app/api/sites.py", line 559, in view_sites
    db.session.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 949, in begin
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun.  Use subtransactions=True to allow subtransactions.
...
```

According to [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.begin.params.subtransactions) `subtransactions` will become obsolete in future versions of sqlalchemy ?

I'm looking for a way to programatically set `autocommit=True` in the beginning of `func3`, and turn it back to `autocommit=True` in the end of `func3`
Is this possible?

Thanks